# App in the docker-container did not want run on PC

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

1. I have spring boot project with one page - Hello word!
2. JAR app perfectly works in a docker container.
3. But in my host computer docker does not want run app. Page not available.
4. docker ps say:

   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                              NAMES
   4b34df7e3986        quality-serv                                              "java -jar quality-s…"   21 hours ago        Up 20 hours                     0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp             quality-service_con
5. But netstat (admin) does not find listeners on same port

---

App work only in the container, not in a personal computer.

I try many dif commands:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d...

docker run --expose 9990 -p 9990:9990 -p 8080:8080 -it  

docker run -d --net=host -P  

docker run -it -d -p
```

They did not help.

---

Run yaml (docker-compose) with image description did not help too...

Comment: is it windows 7 or 10? are you using docker for windows?

Comment: How do you know about "2. JAR app perfectly work in docker container."? did you login into container bash?

Comment: Please also leave a copy of the Dockerfile you used to create the image from which you ran the container

Answer (score 1):

First make sure, when creating the container, the Dockerfile was exposing port 8080 `EXPOSE 8080`.

Then, if your application runs on port 8080, `docker run -p 8080:8080` should be the command. Don't add `-d` by now, so you don't run detached mode and can see the logs.

Comment: Yes. In dockerfile i use: EXPOSE 8080

Comment: docker run --net=host -P   quality-serv
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)


2019-05-16 07:44:38.855  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080